# what's the precedence on asset pipeline

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, turbolinks

what's the precedence on asset pipeline

I want to overwrite part of `ace.css` style with `user.css.scss`

Stylesheet file `ace.css` in vendor folder is expected to be overriden by  `user.css.scss` .

But it didn't work at all (given I include **ace.css** between **user.css.scss**, that is I imported the **user.css** twice )

#### user.css.scss

```
div#user_bottom a.btn{
  color: red;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

#### ace.css

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF !important;
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

#### layout file

I tried to put the user.css.scss TWICE

one is before the ace.css

and the other after the ace.css

```
= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller]
%link{href: asset_path("ace-admin-theme/css/uncompressed/ace.css"), rel: "stylesheet"}/
= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller]
```

#### The haml

```
  %div#user_bottom
    %a.btn{class: "btn-#{button_color}",href: url }
```

#### result

**user.css.scss** still be override by ace.css

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem of ordering your files.

If you have an element

```
<div id="user_bottom"><a class="btn">A</a></div>
```

The more precise CSS selector will be the last used. So `div#user_bottom a.btn` will be used before `.btn` because it's more "precise".

Replace your `ace.css` first line by

```
.btn, div#user_bottom a.btn {
```

To be more "precise", and defined **after** the first rule.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html says

> To find the value for an element/property combination, user agents must apply the following sorting order:
>
> Find all declarations that apply to the element and property in question, for the target media type. Declarations apply if the associated selector matches the element in question and the target medium matches the media list on all @media rules containing the declaration and on all links on the path through which the style sheet was reached.
>   Sort according to importance (normal or important) and origin (author, user, or user agent). In ascending order of precedence:
>
> - user agent declarations
> - user normal declarations
> - author normal declarations
> - author important declarations
> - user important declarations
>
> Sort rules with the same importance and origin by specificity of selector: more specific selectors will override more general ones. Pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes are counted as normal elements and classes, respectively.
>
> Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins. Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any declarations in the style sheet itself.